# Clonar selects dependientes en 3 niveles

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo un código en el que me clona la primer fila de una tabla mediante un boton "+", la cual tiene tres `select` cada uno dependiente del otro, es decir dependiendo de lo que yo seleccione en el primer `select` (soc), me listará unas opciones en el segundo(term), y a su vez me listará unas opciones en el segundo(grado), aunque no copia los `select`, y las opciones se despliegan bien solo si es la primera fila, y es ese el problema, cuando clono una fila, y voy a seleccionar una de las opciones del primer `select` bien, pero cuando voy a seleccionar la del segundo me llama las opciones del `select` de la fila superior en (term) y (grado), no se que hacer pues se que si clona la fila, estos son los códigos:

**FORMULARIO**

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table align="center" class="table bg-info" id="tabla">
         <!---Campo CTCAE v4.0 SOC-->
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>SOC</th>
               <th>TERM</th>
               <th>GRADO</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <!---Campo CTCAE v4.0 SOC-->
            <tr class="fila-fija">
               <td>
                  <select id="soc" name="soc[]">
                     <option value="NULL">SELECCIONA...</option>
                     <option value="Blood ">Blood</option>
                     <option value="Cardiac">Cardiac</option>
                     <option value="Congenital">Congenital</option>
                     <option value="Ear and labyrinth disorders">Ear and labyrinth disorders</option>
                     <option value="Endocrine disorders">Endocrine disorders</option>
                     <option value="Eye disorders">Eye disorders</option>
                     <option value="Gastrointestinal disorders">Gastrointestinal disorders</option>
                     <option value="General disorders and administration site conditions">General disorders and administration site conditions</option>
                     <option value="Hepatobiliary disorders">Hepatobiliary disorders</option>
                     <option value="Immune system disorders">Immune system disorders</option>
                     <option value="Infections">Infections and infestations</option>
                     <option value="Injury">Injury</option>
                     <option value="Investigations">Investigations</option>
                     <option value="Metabolism">Metabolism</option>
                     <option value="Musculoskeletal">Musculoskeletal</option>
                     <option value="Neoplasms benign, malignant and unspecified">Neoplasms </option>
                     <option value="Nervous system disorders">Nervous system disorders</option>
                     <option value="Pregnancy">Pregnancy</option>
                     <option value="Psychiatric disorders">Psychiatric disorders</option>
                     <option value="Renal and urinary disorders">Renal and urinary disorders</option>
                     <option value="Reproductive system">Reproductive system</option>
                     <option value="Respiratory">Respiratory</option>
                     <option value="Skin ">Skin </option>
                     <option value="Surgical ">Surgical </option>
                     <option value="Vascular disorders">Vascular disorders</option>
                  </select>
               </td>
               <!---Campo CTCAE v4.0 Term-->
               <td><select name="term[]" id="term"></select></td>
               <!---Campo CTCAE Grado-->
               <td><select name="grado[]" id="grado"></select></td>
               <td class="eliminar"><input type="button" value="-"/></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="btn-der"><button id="adicional" name="adicional" type="button" class="btn btn-warning">+</button></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**CÓDIGO PARA CLONAR**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.js"></script>
<?php require('Includes/getPrueba.php'); ?>


<script>
  $(function(){
// Clona la fila oculta que tiene los campos base, y la agrega al final de la tabla
$("#adicional").on('click', function(){
$("#tabla tbody tr:eq(0)").clone(true).removeClass('fila-fija').appendTo("#tabla tbody");

});

  $(document).on("click",".eliminar",function(){
      var parent = $(this).parents().get(0);
      $(parent).remove();
  });

  });
</script>
```

**CÓDIGO EN AJAX PARA EL ARRAY**

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#soc").change(function(){
            //alert($('select[name=soc]').val());
            $("#soc option:selected").each(function () {
            soc = $(this).val();
            $.post("Includes/getTermPrueba.php", { soc: soc}, 
                    g    function(data){
                            $("#term").html(data);
            });
        });  
   })
}); 

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#term").change(function(){
            //alert($('select[name=soc]').val());
            $("#term option:selected").each(function () {
            term = $(this).val();
            $.post("Includes/getGrado.php", { term: term }, 
                         function(data){
                            $("#grado").html(data);
            });
        });  
   })
});


</script>
```

**EJEMPLO**
[![En el primer  anidado todo bien...][1]][1]
[![Pero al darle en el botoncito "+" si agrega nuevamente los , sin embargo el select 2 y 3 se quedan con las mismas opciones del primero que fue elegido.][2]][2]
[![Y así sigue sin importar la cantidad que se agregue o quite.][3]][3]

**MODIFICACIÓN DE CÓDIGO**
He hecho caso a sus correcciones, así mismo quedando como lo siguiente... pero sigue sin funcionar :(

**FORMULARIO**

```
    <html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.js"></script>
<?php require('Includes/getPrueba.php'); ?>


<script>
  $(function(){
// Clona la fila oculta que tiene los campos base, y la agrega al final de la tabla
$("#adicional").on('click', function(){
$("#tabla tbody tr:eq(0)").clone(true).removeClass('fila-fija').appendTo("#tabla tbody");
});

  $(document).on("click",".eliminar",function(){
      var parent = $(this).parents().get(0);
      $(parent).remove();
  });

  });
</script>

</head>

<body>
<table align="center" class="table bg-info" id="tabla">
 <!---Campo CTCAE v4.0 SOC-->
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th>SOC</th>
  <th>TERM</th>
  <th>GRADO</th>
 </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
 <!---Campo CTCAE v4.0 SOC-->
 <tr>
<td>
<select class="soc" id="soc" name="soc[]">
<option value="NULL">SELECCIONA...</option>
<option value="Blood and lymphatic system disorders">Blood and lymphatic system disorders</option>
<option value="Cardiac disorders">Cardiac disorders</option>
<option value="Congenital, familial and genetic disorders">Congenital, familial and genetic disorders</option>
<option value="Ear and labyrinth disorders">Ear and labyrinth disorders</option>
<option value="Endocrine disorders">Endocrine disorders</option>
<option value="Eye disorders">Eye disorders</option>
<option value="Gastrointestinal disorders">Gastrointestinal disorders</option>
<option value="Nervous system disorders">Nervous system disorders</option>
<option value="Pregnancy, puerperium and perinatal conditions">Pregnancy, puerperium and perinatal conditions</option>
<option value="Psychiatric disorders">Psychiatric disorders</option>
<option value="Renal and urinary disorders">Renal and urinary disorders</option>
<option value="Vascular disorders">Vascular disorders</option>
</select>
 </td>
  <!---Campo CTCAE v4.0 Term-->
 <td><select name="term[]" id="term" class="term"></select></td>
<!---Campo CTCAE Grado-->
 <td><select name="grado[]" id="grado" class="grado"></select></td>

 <td class="eliminar"><input type="button" value="-"/></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<div class="btn-der">
  <button id="adicional" name="adicional" type="button" class="btn btn-warning">+</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**TRAER OPCIONES DE SELECT**

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".soc").change(function(){
            var tr =  $(this).parent().parent();
            alert($('.soc').val());
            soc = $(this).val();
            $.post("Includes/getTerm.php", { soc: soc }, 
                         function(data){
                            $("#term").html(data);
            });
   })

    $(".term").change(function(){
            alert($('.term').val());
            var tr =  $(this).parent().parent();
            term = $(this).val();
            $.post("Includes/getGrado.php", { term: term }, 
                         function(data){
                            $("#grado").html(data);
            });  
   })

});
</script>
```

**CARGAR TERM**

```
<?php
require('../conexion.php');
  $soc = $_POST['soc'];

$sqlT = "select term from dbo.ctcae  where soc='$soc'";
$resultadoT = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sqlT );


$html = "<option value=''>SELECCIONA...</option>";

while($rowT = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $resultadoT, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) )  {
$html.= "<option value='".$rowT['term']."'>".$rowT['term']."</option>";
} 

echo $html;

?>
```

**CARGAR GRADO**

```
 <?php
    require ('../conexion.php');

    $term = $_POST['term'];

$sqlG = "select grado1, grado2, grado3, grado4, grado5 from dbo.ctcae  where term='$term'";
$resultadoG = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sqlG );

while($rowG = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $resultadoG, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) )  {
        $html.= "<option value='".$rowG['grado1']."'>".$rowG['grado1']."</option>";
        $html.= "<option value='".$rowG['grado2']."'>".$rowG['grado2']."</option>";
        $html.= "<option value='".$rowG['grado3']."'>".$rowG['grado3']."</option>";
        $html.= "<option value='".$rowG['grado4']."'>".$rowG['grado4']."</option>";
        $html.= "<option value='".$rowG['grado5']."'>".$rowG['grado5']."</option>";
    }
    echo $html;
?>
```

---

El primer select bien, pero al pucharle el botoncito de "+" me añade otro select sin embargo este se descontrola totalmente, sigue trayendo la opc del select pasado....
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se descontrolan todas las opciones, el 2do select afecta al primero y las opciones que ya estaban elegidas se borran...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé si tenga que ver con algo de la BD de dónde jalo mis opciones:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**NUEVO ERROR!**
Perfecto, aunque el error persiste en cuanto que si agregas otra opción la parte de grado sigue seleccionada como si fuera del primer select....
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al seleccionar la nueva opción en este caso "Cardiac" me aparece como si tuviera los valores del pasado...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque si cambia, las opciones le corresponden a "cardiac"...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que aunque las opciones cambien cada uno con sus respectivos, me arrastra los valores del primer  de , entonces al guardalo en la BD todos se guardaran con el mismo valor.

Comment: ¿@Jaqueline una consulta siempre pasa con todos las filas que clonas que cuando seleccionas un select  hace referencia al primero?

Comment: @bercklynCarlosviza es un select anidado, el segundo depende de la elección del primero y el tercero depende de la elección del segundo.

Comment: espero te sirva mi respuesta. Me avisas como te va.

Comment: @bercklynCarlosviza #Gracias, ya lo he intentado, pero no me da resultado!

Comment: Jaqueline Duran que error te sale cuando  probaste la solución.

Comment: Bueno es que en ese código ya existen opciones preestablecidas que van a aparecer, y yo las envió y regreso  $.post("Includes/getTerm.php", { soc: soc }, 
       function(data){
       $("#term").html(data);
   });´´

Comment: Hice una edición al final de mi respuesta que creo debería funcionarte, De todas maneras te recomendaría que intentaras entender mi respuesta original y podrías hacer funcionar tu código. ya que es justamente lo que necesitas. Como lo explico en mi respuesta si sigues usando los ID (En jquery "#") nunca va a funcionarte porque tus selects no son únicos, son copias de los de la primera linea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explicación de Error

El error recae en la asignación de la función `.change()` ya que lo haces seleccionando el id de un elemento `$("#soc").change()`. Al hacer eso solo reconocerá la acción del primer elemento  que encuentre con ese id por eso cuando haces click en tu primer select clonado hace que cambie el segundo select del tr que clonaste  porque en esta linea `$("#soc option:selected")` apunta a ese elemento.

## Solución

Para solucionar el error tendrías cambiar un poco la lógica de como haces la los eventos `change()` haciendo que apunte hacia selectores de clases que agregaras a tu select. Por otro lado para no hacer confundir la agregación del html al select de costado realizaras una búsqueda en un bloque de html en el cual solo se encuentre el select con ese id, para ello te ubicaras en el tr en donde haras un `find()`. Como sugerencia  no uses `each()` para una sola acción.

## Solución Editada

Con los cambios que hiciste solo te falto agregar en la parte en donde seteas el html  la referencia a cual select se lo piensas hacer por ello dentro de la función `$.post()` deberás agregar el cambio de ejemplo que pongo abajo.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".soc").change(function(){
            var tr =  $(this).parent().parent();
            alert($('.soc').val());
            soc = $(this).val();
            $.post("Includes/getTerm.php", { soc: soc }, 
                         function(data){
                            //esta linea se modifica  para buscar 
                            //el select del  tr donde estas
                            tr.find("#term").html(data); 
            });
   })

    $(".term").change(function(){
            alert($('.term').val());
            var tr =  $(this).parent().parent();
            term = $(this).val();
            $.post("Includes/getGrado.php", { term: term }, 
                         function(data){
                            //esta linea se modifica  para buscar 
                            //el select del  tr donde estas
                            tr.find("#grado").html(data);
            });  
   })

});
</script>
```

[Solucion parecida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/146510/c%C3%B3mo-reordenar-el-n%C3%BAmero-que-se-agrega-mediante-un-contador-al-eliminar-un-fila)

```js
$(function() {
  // Clona la fila oculta que tiene los campos base, y la agrega al final de la tabla
  $("#adicional").on('click', function() {
    var tr = $("#tabla tbody tr:eq(0)").clone(true).removeClass('fila-fija');
    tr.find("#term").empty(); //aqui se limpia el select term
    tr.find("#grado").empty(); //aqui se limpia el select grado
    tr.appendTo("#tabla tbody"); // agregas el row clonado a la tabla
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".eliminar", function() {
    var parent = $(this).parents().get(0);
    $(parent).remove();
  });

  $(".soc").change(function() { //esta parte se cambiara a que haga la funcion en los los select de class soc
    var tr =  $(this).parent().parent(); //obtenemos el tr padre para hacer la busqueda
    
    //El each esta demas
    //select.find("#soc option:selected").each(function() {
      soc = $(this).val();
      
      //comento tu post solo como de ejemplo
      //$.post("Includes/getTermPrueba.php", {
      //    soc: soc
      //  },

      //   function(data) {
      //aqui buscamos solo en tr al select por el id
       tr.find("#term").html( '<option value="Respiratory">Respiratory</option>' 
                      + '<option value="Skin ">Skin </option>'
                      + '<option value="Surgical ">Surgical </option>'
                      + '<option value="Vascular disorders">Vascular disorders</option>');
      //   });
    //});
  })

  $(".term").change(function() { //esta parte se cambiara a que haga la funcion en los los select de class term

    var tr =  $(this).parent().parent(); // tr padre para hacer la busqueda
    //$("#term option:selected").each(function() {
      term = $(this).val();
      //$.post("Includes/getGrado.php", {
      //    term: term
      //  },
      //  function(data) {
        tr.find("#grado").html('<option value="Respiratory">Respiratory</option>' 
                      + '<option value="Skin ">Skin </option>'
                      + '<option value="Surgical ">Surgical </option>'
                      + '<option value="Vascular disorders">Vascular disorders</option>');
      //});
    //});
  })
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <table align="center" class="table bg-info" id="tabla">
    <!---Campo CTCAE v4.0 SOC-->
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>SOC</th>
        <th>TERM</th>
        <th>GRADO</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <!---Campo CTCAE v4.0 SOC-->
      <tr class="fila-fija">
        <td>
          <select id="soc" name="soc[]" class="soc">
                     <option value="NULL">SELECCIONA...</option>
                     <option value="Blood ">Blood</option>
                     <option value="Cardiac">Cardiac</option>
                     <option value="Congenital">Congenital</option>
                     <option value="Ear and labyrinth disorders">Ear and labyrinth disorders</option>
                     <option value="Endocrine disorders">Endocrine disorders</option>
                     <option value="Eye disorders">Eye disorders</option>
                     <option value="Gastrointestinal disorders">Gastrointestinal disorders</option>
                     <option value="General disorders and administration site conditions">General disorders and administration site conditions</option>
                     <option value="Hepatobiliary disorders">Hepatobiliary disorders</option>
                     <option value="Immune system disorders">Immune system disorders</option>
                     <option value="Infections">Infections and infestations</option>
                     <option value="Injury">Injury</option>
                     <option value="Investigations">Investigations</option>
                     <option value="Metabolism">Metabolism</option>
                     <option value="Musculoskeletal">Musculoskeletal</option>
                     <option value="Neoplasms benign, malignant and unspecified">Neoplasms </option>
                     <option value="Nervous system disorders">Nervous system disorders</option>
                     <option value="Pregnancy">Pregnancy</option>
                     <option value="Psychiatric disorders">Psychiatric disorders</option>
                     <option value="Renal and urinary disorders">Renal and urinary disorders</option>
                     <option value="Reproductive system">Reproductive system</option>
                     <option value="Respiratory">Respiratory</option>
                     <option value="Skin ">Skin </option>
                     <option value="Surgical ">Surgical </option>
                     <option value="Vascular disorders">Vascular disorders</option>
                  </select>
        </td>
        <!---Campo CTCAE v4.0 Term-->
        <td><select name="term[]" id="term" class="term"></select></td>
        <!---Campo CTCAE Grado-->
        <td><select name="grado[]" id="grado"></select></td>
        <td class="eliminar"><input type="button" value="-" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="btn-der"><button id="adicional" name="adicional" type="button" class="btn btn-warning">+</button></div>
</body>

</html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75155/discussion-on-answer-by-bercklyn-carlosviza-clonar-selects-dependientes-en-3-niv).

Comment: @Jorgesys ¿La opción de chat ya no se abre de forma automática? ¿De ser así como abro una sala de chat?.

Answer (score 1):

Primero a los select debes identificarlos con `class` y no con `id`, los id son para identificar elementos únicos y vos estas clonando selects por lo que ya no son únicos.

Por otro lado cuando haces los eventos `change` de cada select, tenes que buscar el select correspondiente para agregarle la respuesta que te devuelve post.

Ejemplo, siendo $(this) la opción seleccionada:

```
$(this).closest("tr").find(".grado").html(respuesta);
```

Por otro lado cuando agregas un nuevo row a la tabla podes borrar el contenido de los selects de la row que estas clonando

Ejemplo, siendo row una variable donde guardamos el tr que acabamos de clonar:

```
row.find('.term').empty(); //vacias el select
row.find('.grado').empty(); //vacias el select
```

Te dejo un ejemplo funcionando con estos cambios que te propongo, espero que te sea de utilidad.

Saludos!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".soc").on("change", function(){
      //llamada a post con $(this).val()
      //suponiendo respuesta "var respuesta"
       var respuesta = '<option value=""></option><option value="test">test</option>';
       $(this).closest("tr").find(".term").html(respuesta);
    });

    $(".term").on("change", function(){
      //llamada a post con $(this).val()
      //suponiendo respuesta "var respuesta"
      var respuesta = '<option value=""></option><option value="test2">test2</option>';
      $(this).closest("tr").find(".grado").html(respuesta);
    });
    
    $("#adicional").on('click', function(){
      var row = $("#tabla tbody tr:eq(0)").clone(true).removeClass('fila-fija');
      row.find('.term').empty(); //vacias el select
      row.find('.grado').empty(); //vacias el select
      row.appendTo("#tabla tbody")
    });
    
    $(".eliminar").on("click",function(){
      var parent = $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table align="center" class="table bg-info" id="tabla">
         <!---Campo CTCAE v4.0 SOC-->
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>SOC</th>
               <th>TERM</th>
               <th>GRADO</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <!---Campo CTCAE v4.0 SOC-->
            <tr class="fila-fija">
               <td>
                  <select class="soc" name="soc[]">
                     <option value="NULL">SELECCIONA...</option>
                     <option value="Blood ">Blood</option>
                     <option value="Cardiac">Cardiac</option>
                     <option value="Congenital">Congenital</option>
                  </select>
               </td>
               <!---Campo CTCAE v4.0 Term-->
               <td><select name="term[]" class="term"></select></td>
               <!---Campo CTCAE Grado-->
               <td><select name="grado[]" class="grado"></select></td>
               <td class="eliminar"><input type="button" value="-"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="fila-fija">
               <td>
                  <select class="soc" name="soc[]">
                     <option value="NULL">SELECCIONA...</option>
                     <option value="Blood ">Blood</option>
                     <option value="Cardiac">Cardiac</option>
                     <option value="Congenital">Congenital</option>
                  </select>
               </td>
               <!---Campo CTCAE v4.0 Term-->
               <td><select name="term[]" class="term"></select></td>
               <!---Campo CTCAE Grado-->
               <td><select name="grado[]" class="grado"></select></td>
               <td class="eliminar"><input type="button" value="-"/></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="btn-der"><button id="adicional" name="adicional" type="button" class="btn btn-warning">+</button></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

Edición en base a tu ultima modificacion, si cambias esto de deberia funcionar:

```
$(".soc").change(function(){

    soc = $(this).val();

    $.post("Includes/getTerm.php", { soc: soc }, 
         function(data){
             $(this).closest("tr").find(".term").html(data);
    });
})

$(".term").change(function(){

    term = $(this).val();

    $.post("Includes/getGrado.php", { term: term }, 
         function(data){
            $(this).closest("tr").find(".grado").html(data);
    });  
})
```

Comment: Hola! Muchas Gracias por responder. Bueno he hecho e interpretado el código, que me has propuesto; sin embargo al cambiar mis `select` a clases....  `<td><select id="term" name="term[]"></select></td>`

Comment: ya no me aparece ninguna opción, no sé si se deba a que lo jalo en otro documento... `$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#soc").change(function(){
            //alert($('select[name=soc]').val());
            $("#soc option:selected").each(function () {
            soc = $(this).val();
            $.post("Includes/getTermPrueba.php", { soc: soc}, 
       function(data){
       $("#term").html(data);
   });
  });  
   })
});`

Comment: ` que a su vez lo jala de este otro....  ` <?php
require('../conexion.php');
  $soc = $_POST['soc'];
 

 
$sqlT = "select term from dbo.ctcae  where soc='$soc'";
$resultadoT = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sqlT );


$html = "<option value=''>SELECCIONA...</option>";

while($rowT = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $resultadoT, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) )  {
$html.= "<option value='".$rowT['term']."'>".$rowT['term']."</option>";
} 

echo $html;

?>`

Comment: Exactamente, fijate que en el codigo que te propuse yo cambie  esos $("#soc").change(... por $(".soc").on("change"

Comment: Listo he realizado los cambios, pero en la palabra tr:eq(0)").clone() si lo pongo "true" la selección no es la correcta sigue quedandose la primer selección, y si le pongo "false" los siguientes select añadidos dejan de funcionar.

Comment: cual linea de la tabla queres clonar?

Comment: He actualizado mi código para explicarme mejor!

Comment: Fijate que esta todo mal formateado, no se entiende el codigo. Adicionalmente no te funcionan los selects en la fila que agregas justamente porque cuando clonas le sacaste el true a la funcion clone, que lo que hace es clonar tambien los eventos de los hijos, en este caso los "change" de los selects.

Comment: He visto tu propuesta, pero si lo integro a mi código deja de funcionar totalmente!